# Running Two Cameras Simultaneously using Emgu CV C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have two IP cameras. I want to run both of them simultaneously. I am using Emgu CV to process images. So here, when I click Start button, my program will check which my cameras are active (get their IP addresses). After getting their IP addresses, my program will use those IPs to get data from database. The condition that I get, my program will be very slow and there is delay for several seconds when capture process is running. Can anyone help me what I must do to solve this problem ? Here what I have done

```
    private void Tombol_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ProsesSemuaKamera();
    }

    private void ProsesSemuaKamera()
    {
       Ping ping = new Ping();
       PingReply pingreply;

       OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
       OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();
       kon.Open();
       string selecturl = "select * from datakamera";
       command.CommandText = selecturl;
       OleDbDataReader bacadata = command.ExecuteReader();

       while (bacadata.Read())
       {
         int counturl = 0;
         pingreply = ping.Send(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());

         if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
         {
           listBox1.Items.Add(bacadata["namakamera"].ToString());
           CaptureSemuaKamera = new Capture(bacadata["urlkamera"].ToString());
           Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrameSemuaKamera);    

         }
         else if (pingreply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
         {
          textBox3.Text += bacadata["namakamera"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
          }
      }
    kon.Close();
 }

    private void ProcessFrameSemuaKamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = CaptureSemuaKamera.QueryFrame();
      SourceBox.Image = sourceImage.Bitmap;
      ProsesKameraSemua();
    }

        private string BuildWhereClause(ListBox lb)
        {
            string WHEREclause = string.Empty;

            foreach (string itm in lb.Items)
            {
                if (WHEREclause == string.Empty)
                {
                    WHEREclause += " where namakamera = '" + itm + "' ";
                }
                else
                {
                    WHEREclause += " OR namakamera = '" + itm + "' ";
                }
            }
            return WHEREclause;
        }

 private void ProsesKameraSemua()
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImage = CaptureSemuaKamera.QueryFrame();
            SourceBox.Image = sourceImage.Bitmap;

            OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            OleDbCommand commandkoord = kon.CreateCommand();
            OleDbCommand commandkoordgaris = kon.CreateCommand();

            kon.Open();
                string selectsemuakoord = "select * from koordinatkotak " + BuildWhereClause(listBox1);
                string selectsemuakoordgaris = "select * from koordinatgaris " + BuildWhereClause(listBox1);

                commandkoord.CommandText = selectsemuakoord;
                commandkoordgaris.CommandText = selectsemuakoordgaris;
                OleDbDataReader bacakoord = commandkoord.ExecuteReader();
                OleDbDataReader bacakoordgaris = commandkoordgaris.ExecuteReader();

                while (bacakoord.Read() && bacakoordgaris.Read())
                {
                    #region Perspective projection

                    PointF[] srcs = new PointF[4];
                    srcs[0] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x1source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y1source"].ToString())); //119, 187
                    srcs[1] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x2source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y2source"].ToString())); //242, 181
                    srcs[2] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x3source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y3source"].ToString())); //253, 225
                    srcs[3] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x4source"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y4source"].ToString())); //112, 231

                    PointF[] dsts = new PointF[4];
                    dsts[0] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x1proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y1proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[1] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x2proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y2proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[2] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x3proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y3proj"].ToString()));
                    dsts[3] = new PointF(int.Parse(bacakoord["x4proj"].ToString()), int.Parse(bacakoord["y4proj"].ToString()));


                    HomographyMatrix mywarpmat = CameraCalibration.GetPerspectiveTransform(srcs, dsts);
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> newImage = sourceImage.WarpPerspective(mywarpmat, 355, 288, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.WARP.CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, new Bgr(0, 0, 0));
                    Image<Gray, Byte> newImageGray = newImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                    Image<Bgr, Byte> imageToShow = newImage.Copy();
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> imageToShowGaris = newImage.Copy();

                    ProjectionBox.Image = newImage.Bitmap;

                    #endregion
  }
}
```